# Display the dataset as a single post

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to make a stories system like Facebook or Instagram. As you can see in the table below `s_id` is unique post id and `uid_fk` post created user id.

[image]

`uid_fk` => *4* created *3* post in this table.

**and**

`uid_fk` => *5* created also *3* post.

If the query is:

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT s_id, uid_fk, stories_img FROM stories_posts") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

then html output looks like this

```
<!--
    id=s_id , 
    data_uidfk=uid_fk ,
    div inside imgage stories_img
-->

<div class="post" id="1" data_uidfk="4">15019557244.jpg</div>
<div class="post" id="2" data_uidfk="5">150021986050.png</div>
<div class="post" id="3" data_uidfk="4">14939786704.gif</div>
<div class="post" id="4" data_uidfk="5">14939786777.jpg</div>

<!--And other posts-->
```

***My question is how can I display dataset as a single post like this***,

```
<!--
        id=s_id , 
        data_uidfk=uid_fk ,
        div inside imgage stories_img
    -->

    <div class="post" data_uidfk="4">
        All uid_fk = 4 posts will be show in this div. 
    </div>
    <div class="post" data_uidfk="5">
        All uid_fk = 5 posts will be show in this div.
    </div>

    <!--And other posts-->
```

*Thank you in advance for your help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your query to:

```
SELECT uid_fk, group_concat(stories_img) as pics
FROM stories_posts
GROUP BY uid_fk
```

The records will be return as:

```
uid_fk   pics
4        pic1,pic2,pi6
5        pic4,pic5,pic7
```

Then explode to set the individual images and place them in the necessary html element.